# Are minifyed Javascript files smaller when semicolons are omitted?

Tags: javascript, minify

I wonder if minifyed Javascript files are smaller when semicolons are omitted in the original file? After reading the following sources, my guess is the minifyer will automatically add a character (typ. a semi comma) to ensure the code still work after being minifyed.

- [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion
- [In JavaScript, is it safe to omit semicolons when file have to be minifyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793770/in-javascript-is-it-safe-to-omit-semicolons-when-file-have-to-be-minifyed)

Comment: You're basically just replacing a newline by a semicolon. Both characters are one byte.